# EF 7 Code first DB creation issue

Tags: entity-framework

I followed a tutorial on pluralsight for ASP .NET 5 and EF 7 using Code First DB.
This is the connection string :

```
"WorldContextConnection": "Server=CVU-OCTAVIANE\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TheWorldDB;Trusted_Connection=true;"
```

I added the initial migration (which worked fine) and then I tried to use a EF 7 feature to create the DB automatically: I created a Context type class where I used Database.EnsureCreated() to create the DB on the first run. This is the context class:

```
public class WorldContext : DbContext
{
    public WorldContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stop> Stops { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connString = Startup.Configuration["Data:WorldContextConnection"];

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I ran the project "A severe error occurred on the current command"

Thanks

Comment: That's a generic error. You may debug that method to find the inner exception.
Just add a try catch and on the catch put a Debugger.Launch(); and the exception occurs it will ask to launch visual studio and you accept it and then you are able to see the full exception.

Comment: @Leandro Soares - I ran the project in Debug mode, but the Inner Exception is null - I have no other info about the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and seem to have resolved it.

I'm not sure if all of the below is required, but are the steps I took

- Deleted all migration .cs files under the Migrations folder
- Deleted TheWorldDB from SQL Server Object Explorer
- Closed Visual Studio
- Upgraded ASP.NET 5 to RC1 Final at get.asp.net
- Opened Visual Studio
- Updated global.json to use "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
- Updated project.json to use latest "dependencies"

  - "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  - "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  - "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  - "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  - "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  - "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  - "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  - "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  - "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  - "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
- Ran dnvm install to get "1.0.0-rc1-final" and switched to it
- Recreated migration with dnx ef migrations add InitialDatabase
- Executed project and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same problem of yours, and I took a few steps less.

- I removed the Migration folder
- I updated my global.json to the default version of sdk that I'm using, (check using "dnvm list") which in my case was "update2".
- Deleted the TheWorlDb from my SQL instance.
- After that, I just generated again the migration of InitialDatabase
- Clear, Build and Rebuild the solution.